# Angular2 passing data between two child components

Tags: forms, angular, router

I have a component with two childcomponents. I show one or the other with using the router with the router-outlet.

I want to take form data inserted in the first child, and use it in the other child which I route to upon submitting the form.

I suspect I need to use @input or @output but I can't find any documentation on how to do it when using the router-outlet.

My current other solution is to save the data in the localstorage when submitting the form in the first child and calling it in the second child. Doesn't seem ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the data via a service. If you create a service, and set the data in child A, you could then retrieve it from child B. The only catch is you need to set this service you create as a provider for the parent class, and not for the child components.

Here is an example of this [Angular 2 passing object via route params possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478994/angular-2-passing-object-via-route-params-possible)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [@ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store) to store data, then inject those into your route components. See the examples there for implementation.