# How to pass data from one child component to another child component in angular2?

Tags: angular

Suppose, i have a componentA and a componentB

```
@Component({
  selector: 'appA',
  templateUrl: './appA.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appA.css']
})
export class componentA{
  constructor(private route: Router) { } 
  moveFront() {
    this.route.navigateByUrl('componentB');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'appB',
  templateUrl: './appB.html',
  styleUrls: ['./appB.css']
})
export class componentB{
  constructor(private route: Router) { } 
  moveBack() {
    this.route.navigateByUrl('componentA');
  }
}
```

now when i call the moveFront() function, componentB gets called but i want to pass some data as well to the component, how can i do that?

both my component is a child component, i want to transfer data to and from the one child component to another child component. how can i do it.

Comment: I would use the store to do this and dispatch whatever I want to be shared between the two to the store right before I navigate to the new component, and when the other component starts up I'd subscribe to that store and get the value. You could also use a service and set a variable in the service and when the second component is created it can actively grab that variable from the service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 passing data between two child components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254379/angular2-passing-data-between-two-child-components)

Comment: Use `ngrx` or a service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share data between components in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026886/how-do-i-share-data-between-components-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 2):

To pass data in Angular you can use
`@Input` to pass data from parent to child
`@Output` to pass data from child to parent

To pass data between sibling components you need either to pass by the parent component or you need to use a service https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-interacts-with-child-via-local-variable

Answer (score 2):

Another option *(if you're only sending string values)* is to use Route params. Similar to query params, it has potential for some pretty gnarly looking URLs, but it's an option. First, you would inject the `ActivatedRoute`:

```js
constructor(private router: Router, private route:ActivatedRoute) { }
```

You would use `router.navigate` instead:

```js
this.router.navigate(['componentB', {myVar:'myValue'}]);
```

Then in your component, subscribe to the route params:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe((data) => {
    this.myVar = data.myVar || 'defaultValue';
  });
}
```

Again, this will only work for strings. Angular calls `.toString()` on any Object passed using this method. If you're wanting to send more complex data, you should use a service/store.

Comment: Use JSON strings, and you have plenty of data available