# Angular 2 passing objects when routing

Tags: angular, oop, typescript, routes

I am trying to pass a object (array) between pages when routing. For this I did exactly what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478994/angular-2-passing-object-via-route-params-possible) said but it doesn't work for me.

**Service**

```
@Injectable ()
export class ReportService extends HttpService {

    public selectedReports: any[] = [];

    public setSelectedReports (id: string, value: any) {
        this.selectedReports[id] = value;
    }

    public removeSelectedReports (id: string) {
         delete this.selectedReports[id];
    }
}
```

**Parent**

```
import { ReportService } from './';

@Component({
  providers: [ReportService]
})

export class ReportComponent {
  constructor (private reportService: ReportService) {}
}
```

**Child 1**

```
import { ReportService } from '../';
@Component({
  template: '<a [routerLink]="['stats']">Stats</a>'
})

export class ReportHomeComponent {

  constructor (private reportService: ReportService) {
    reportService.setSelectedReports (1, 'hello')
  }
}
```

**Child 2**

```
import { ReportService } from '../';

@Component({
})

export class ReportStatsComponent {

  constructor (private reportService: ReportService) {
    console.log(reportService.selectedReports)
  }
}
```

If I click on the `a` in the first child I get redirected towards the second child. Before changing pages, the `selectedReports[]` is filled. After changing pages, it is empty. Am I missing something?

I know this question has been asked before but I decided to ask the question anyway on request within the comment section of the answer given in the link at the top of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be importing the service two different ways.  In the parent component you are using:

```
@Component({
  providers: [ReportService]  //<--unique instance injected into this component
})
```

This creates a new instance and injects it into this component and sub-component tree.

If you have the `ReportService` also specified in the `providers` array of your `@NgModule` then the children are likely getting their instance from there.

For shared services like this, I recommend only adding the service to the `providers` array in the `@NgModule`.  This provides a single instance to all components in that module.  Whereas the `providers` array in the component decorators provides a unique instance to that component.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [ReportService],  //<--inject service here to be global to module
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: I have replaced the provider to the module but the `selectedReports` is still empty.

The module of the parent is now the only location where it's provided.

Comment: It would seem to me that if the service is providing an empty array after modifying the array, that it or the service is being constructed again after route change.  What happens if you remove the `= []` and only create the array in `setSelectedReports ` if it's undefined?

Comment: `selectedReports` is undefined when loading the new page

Comment: Hmm....  I'm doing this same thing several places in one of my apps and don't have any issues.  Either the service is being created more than once or something is clearing it out such as a whole page refresh that restarts the app.

Comment: I have placed a `console.log` between the `imports` and `@Injectable ()` which is only called when loading the first page. While redirecting to the second page there is no log to be found.

Comment: I don't have to import the parents in the children right?

Comment: No.  Importing the service in the constructor is enough.  Only provide the service at the module level and all components should get the same instance.

Comment: "Whereas the providers array in the component decorators provides a unique instance to that component." - Million dollar statement! Saved me hours! Thanks!