# Angular2 Primeng Data table selected row passing to other component using routers

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, primeng

I have a primeng Data table and I want to pass selected row to other page through routers. Ex: I have a student data table and when I select one student row and click on submit button, It should display the details in StudentDetails Page.

Here I can able to select the row and able to pass the data to student component. But unable to pass data to student details component.

```
export class Student {

selectedRow:Student;// I can able to assign selected row here

navigateStudentDetail(){

this.router.navigate(['./studentdetail']);

}
```

I can able to pass studentId using query param, But I want to pass my student object to studentdetails component. But unable to do it.

Is there any easy way to achieve this? Please help me

Comment: Using providers I resolved this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478994/angular-2-passing-object-via-route-params-possible link helped me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's overkill to use a service just to pass some paramenters to another component. You can use NavigationExtras to add custom data along with the Url that you want to navigate to.

```
import { NavigationExtras} from '@angular/router';
//You will need navigations extras from Router.
```

somewhere in your component..

```
      let dataNav:NavigationExtras={queryParams:"somekey":"someValue",
"someOtherKey":"someOtherValue"}};
  this.router.navigate(['/path/whatever/'],dataNav);
```

then in the target component..

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
//you will need something like this
```

instantiate ActivatedRoute in your constructor like this

```
constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router){}
```

finally get the params sent by the first component..

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.route.queryParams
.subscribe(params =>{
  this.someOtherKeyReceived=params['someOtherKey']
});
```

}